# C# Replacing in long string always replace more than I write

Tags: c#, string, replace

I need to change `"T0"` to `"T1"` in gcode file. So, I saved gcode file to `string[]` (array splitted by new line) and call method `Replace`. String has cca **5k** of lines.
Replace block:

```
 // Lines of file
 string[] lines = gcode_prefab.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None); 

 // Replacing
 for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
 {
     if (lines[i].Contains("T0"))
         lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("T0", "T1");
 }
```

Then, after replacing I will `Join` it to `string` by new line and save it as file via `File.WriteLine()` method.
And **result is wrong**. `"T0"` is replaced by `"T1"`, but new file(replaced) has *much fewer lines*. Original file has `5484` lines and new file has `5354` lines, how it is possible?
And there is another problem, Replace method is replacing more things than just "T0" and deleting some lines.
For example:
[Image of differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvH0u.png)

New string is tottally different, how it is possible?

Comment: Side note: `if (lines[i].Contains("T0"))` is *redundant* and can be dropped

Comment: `File.WriteAllText(@"c:\MyFile.txt", File.ReadAllText(@"c:\MyFile.txt").Replace("T0", "T1"));`

Comment: Or don't bother splitting them into lines at all. Just read the whole file in as a single string, call Replace a single time, and write the string out again. Why bother splitting? (Exactly as Dmitry was suggesting while I was typing...)

Comment: That image is from several hundred lines into the file -- it's possible that the diff tool has gotten confused by that point, and is trying to find similarities between completely different parts of the file. I'd focus on the first difference it finds.

Comment: Did you check `lines.length` after assigning?

Comment: If you write the file with multi threading, don't share same file stream with multiple threads. It is not thread safe.